# Solution of the ordinary differential equation $y''+\sin(x)y'+2y=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have the following ordinary differential equation before me:
$y''+\sin(x)y'+2y=1$.

I have to find its PI(particular integral).My strategy is to come up with the solution of corresponding homogeneous equation i.e.
$y''+\sin(x)y'+2y=0$
and then use the method of variation of parameters to determine PI.
But I am stuck at finding the solution of homogeneous equation. Could you please suggest a way out here?

Comment: It's easy to guess $y=1/2$ is a particular solution to the nonhomo one.

Comment: @Just a user BTW, is there a way out for the homogeneous part?

Comment: I'm not sure, but WolframAlpha doesn't pop out an answer, so I assume there is no known closed form. We can compute the Wronskian is $e^{-\cos(x)}$, and but no follow-up from there. If we can get one solution, we can use the Wronskian (or variation of parameters) to get a second one.

Comment: @Justauser Mathematica gives a solution involving a holonomic function.

Comment: @Parcly_Taxel. Thanks for telling us. It's no surprise that we can write down the solution in terms of some special functions, but they are probably not elementary. Maybe those functions can be used to show the solutions are not elementary, but I am always afraid of special functions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, since the coefficient of $y$ and the right-hand side are both constants, a particular solution (integral) is given by the constant function $y=\frac12$, which is what you wanted.

To get solutions of the *homogeneous* part, however, requires some trickery. Since $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, suppose $y(x)=z(w)=z(e^{ix})$, then rewrite in terms of $z$ and $w$. We find that $z$ is a holonomic function defined by
$$2w^2z''+(-w^2+2w+1)z'-4z=0$$
and while this cannot be simplified to named functions it does give an [effective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function#Algorithms_and_software) way of computing any solution to the original differential equation as $y(x)=z(e^{ix})+\frac12$ plus initial conditions.